# How to upload file (.pdf) using WK WebView in Swift?

Tags: swift, wkwebview, ios13, swift5, ios12

Using WK WebView, I am not able to select .pdf below iOS 13. .pdf files are selectable only in iOS 13+ devices. So, how to manipulate with file selection choices? What delegate method of WK WebView will enable us to control the navigation of document/image upload process, if any upload action button is pressed inside web view?

Answer (score 0):

I used this before. It appears ok from my experience.

```
// Create an IBOutlet webView
 
override func viewDidLoad() {
   
let pdfFilePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mydocument", withExtension: "pdf")
let urlRequest = URLRequest.init(url: pdfFilePath!)
webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
webView.load(request)
self.view.addSubview(webView) 
}
```

The other alternative, use safari services SFSafariViewController. Hope this helps. Good luck!